# ADF Dataflow - Replace spaces with underscore in column names

Tags: azure-data-factory

To remove spaces with underscore I am using replace($$,' ','_') expression in Select transformation

It works for a column "Period Key" and makes it "Period_Key" but for another column "Week in Month Description" it makes it "Week_in Month Description". So it is replacing only first occurrence

Can someone try this? Or how can we write regex for this?

[image]

Comment: Can you try clicking on data preview in that transformation and see if the column is correctly reflected there? Might just be a UI bug in the Inspect pane.

Comment: @MarkKromer - It worked using regexReplace function. I have posted other related question in below. Appreciate some guidance.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63639372/adf-dataflow-convert-multiple-csv-to-parquet

Answer (score 1):

I used below function and it worked

```
regexReplace($$,' ','_')
```