# ADF / Dataflow - Convert Multiple CSV to Parquet

Tags: azure-data-factory

In ADLS Gen2, TextFiles folder has 3 CSV files. Column names are different in each file.

We need to convert all 3 CSV files to 3 parquet files and put it in ParquetFiles folder

I tried to use Copy Activity and it fails because the column names have empty space in it and parquet files doesn't allow it

To remove spaces, I used Data flow: Source -> Select (replace space by underscore in col name) and sink. This worked for a single file. When I tried to do it for all 3 files, it tries to merge 3 files and generates single file with incorrect data.

How to solve this, mainly removing spaces from column names in all files. What would be the other options here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipeline: ForEach activity (loop over CSV files in folder and send in current iteration item to data flow as param) -> Data Flow activity with source that points to that folder (parameterize the file name in the source path)

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 datasets, one in csv with wildcard format, the other in parquet. I used the Data Copy Activity using the parquet data set as sink and csv data set as source. I set the copy behavior to Merge files.